# Spark serialization error using LocalDateTime

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Code -

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("/tmp/abc.csv")
rdd.first.split(",").zipWithIndex
val rows=rdd.filter(x => !x.contains("ID") && !x.contains("Case Number"))
val split1=rows.map(x => x.split(","))
split1.take(3)
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
val format=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s a")
val dates=split1.map( x => LocalDateTime.parse( x(2) , format))
```

Error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)

Comment: are you using the default serializer or Kryo? (or something else)

Answer (score 1):

Rather ugly way to handle this is to push format initialization inside anonymous function:

```
split1.map(x => 
  LocalDateTime.parse(x(2), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s a")))
```